# Visual Studio 2015 can't show data tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, localdb

I have recently installed visual studio 2015 community edition.
I created a small web app in asp.net mvc. I was able to connect and save data in the localdb.
But when I connect to localdb through the server explorer, and right click on a table, I only get the options 'copy', 'refresh' and 'properties'.
Coming from visual studio 2013, there i got the option 'show data'.

So how do i show the database tables in vs2015, what am i missing?

thank you in advance.